# Create XML from spesific excel range

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I need help filling XML from specific excel columns using cycle until last cell in the column L1 and L2.

For example I have Information stored in 2 excel sheet columns:

L1       Value1  Value2  Value3

L2
Value1a
Value2a
Value3a

My expected XML output:

```
<Fields Count="6">
<Field Name="L1-1">Value1</Field>
<Field Name="L1-2">Value2</Field>
<Field Name="L1-3">Value3</Field>
<Field Name="L2-1">Value1a</Field>
<Field Name="L2-2">Value2a</Field>
<Field Name="L2-3">Value3a</Field>
<Fields/>
```

It should be some sort of cycle. Also count value would be also greate to calculate based on total number.

Comment: The example is very unclear: Value2 is not present, Value3a exists on two places, Value3 seems to appear on a wrong location and L1 and L2 have a different format.

Comment: Basically I need some code that could be used to take value from excel sheet column until last empty row and convert to node

Answer (score 0):

As follows, for example shown,

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestXML()
    Dim Xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, strXML As String, loopRange As Range, count As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Set loopRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B4")
    count = loopRange.count - loopRange.Columns.count
    strXML = vbNullString
    strXML = "<Fields Count=" & Chr$(34) & count & Chr$(34) & ">"
    For j = 1 To loopRange.Columns.count
        For i = 2 To loopRange.Rows.count
            strXML = strXML & "<Field Name=""" & loopRange.Columns(j).Cells(1) & "-" & i - 1 & """>" & loopRange.Cells(i, j) & "</Field>"
        Next i
    Next j
    strXML = strXML & "</Fields>"

    Set Xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Xmldoc.LoadXML strXML

    Debug.Print Xmldoc.DocumentElement.Text
    Debug.Print Xmldoc.SelectNodes("//Field").Length

End Sub
```

---

**Data layout:**

[image: Data]